# Two login screen in one view MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is create a login page with two login screen for two different type of users.

For One Login Screen, I did this-

I created a model like-

```
public class User1{

[Required(ErrorMessage = "MSG1", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string Id {get; set;}
[Required(ErrorMessage = "MSG2", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
[DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
public string Password {get; set;}

}
```

Form -

```
@model Test.Models.User1
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()          
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Id)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

And the controller is -

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(User1 u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
      //My Code
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

I want to add another login screen here for User2 Type. Can this be possible on the same view??

Comment: Why would you use the same view for two different models?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no difference between the fields that each user type uses to login (i.e. if they both use Id and Password) then I would suggest using the one 'User' model to bind to on your controller and then within your controller handle how you will figure out of what type of user it is and return an appropriate view.

Alternatively, if you can't do this you can just add a second Login form that posts to a different action on the controller (i.e. LoginUserType2). For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginUserType1(User1 u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //My Code
    }
    return View(u);
}
..
..
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginUserType2(User1 u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //My Code
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

Edit:

The way I would do this would be to create a UserViewModel class that represents all the fields on the page. For example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string PasswordType1 { get; set; }
    public string PasswordType2 { get; set; }
}
```

This could then be used as the model for the page and you could post it to both actions as below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginUserType1(UserViewModel u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // Login with UserId and PasswordType1
    }
    return View(u);
}
..
..
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginUserType2(UserViewModel u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        // Login with Username and PasswordType2
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

Each form would post to one of the two actions and you could use whatever fields from the ViewModel as needed in each case. It's not ideal but I think it will work for what you want.

Comment: Both models are different but when creating form how will i differentiate between two different models in same view...

Comment: I've updated the answer per your comment. It probably isn't the most elegant solution but I think would work for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with the help of ViewBag like this. First in your Controller
   create a dynamic property with **ViewBag** like if your user is of type1 then

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //check your user type and set it to true/false
  ViewBag.UserType1 = true;
}

if(ViewBag.UserType1 != null)
{
   @if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.UserType1))
   {
      //Return view for user of type1 
   }
   else
   {
     //return view for user of type2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use editor templates, they allow a hierarchical display of data. For example you could do:

```
public class User1 {}
public class User2 {}
public class Login
{
  public object User { get; set; }
}
```

Login.cshtml:

```
@model Login
<!-- container html for login screen -->
<div>
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.User);
</div>
```

/EditorTemplates/User1.cshtml:

```
@model User1
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginUser1", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()          
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
    }
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Id)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Id)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```